# IE7 does not respect z-index

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, z-index

Running in compatibility mode the calendar below renders behind the textboxes below. IE8 displays the calendar how I need it to.

My CSS

```
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_container 
{
border:1px solid #7F9DB9; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
z-index : 1004 ;   
width:190px;
}
```

the textboxes which are overlaying the calendar don't have their z-index set anywhere although I have tried in my server side code to set their z-index to -1 if I detect IE7 to no avail. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 32):

IE has problems with z-index. Most browsers treat the page as one continuous stacking context, but in IE, positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0.

As mentioned in this article:

http://trwa.ca/2012/03/ie-z-index-bug-and-how-to-squash-it/

try giving the calendar's parent element an even higher z-index.

Comment: I shouldn't say IE7 has "problems", it just handles z-index differently than other browsers do.

Comment: And that would be a problem.

Comment: What a serendipitous posting - I was having the same problem

Comment: To be a bit more precise: find the point where the two competing elements have ancestors that are siblings (where they are both inside the same element). Take the sibling that is an ancestor of the element you want to be on top, and give *that* a position (e.g. position: relative) and a high z-index. It might be the parent, or it might be further than that.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it on top with an additional transparent background image. IE8. SASS:

```
  #galerie-link {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 25px;
    left: 40px;
    a {
      display: block;
      width: 185px;
      height: 90px;
      background-image: url(../images/transparent.png);
    }
  }
```

Comment: your transparent spacer gif saved by ass. thank you.