# Link not working in overlapping Div

Tags: html, hyperlink, overlap

Making a footer for a web site I stumbled upon some strange behavior of overlapping Divs. You can see an example at:

http://mike.latysheva.ru/test.html

The issue is that second link is not clickable in IE7 and at least some versions of IE8. Works fine in IE9 and Firefox.

Here is the code, it is pretty simple (you can see full code in page source):

```
<div style="height: 120px; width: 200px; background: #DDDDDD; postion:relative;">
  <div style="height: 40px; padding: 10px;postion:relative;">
    <a ...[have to remove an actual link in order to post it here]>Test Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 40px; padding: 10px;postion:relative;">
     <a ...[have to remove an actual link in order to post it here]">Test Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:250px;height:100px; background:#777777;margin-top:-60px;position:relative;z-index: -10;"></div>
```

What can be wrong with the code? Does it have something to do with z-index: -10? I'm totally confused ... Please help ...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the parent of the z-index:-10 div a z-index:1.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Z-index broken in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290191/z-index-broken-in-ie8)

and this one

[IE7 / IE8 z-index problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466695/ie7-ie8-z-index-problem)

Comment: Thank you for this info. Never had trouble with this before. We live - we learn!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your first two divs are given `postion` instead of `position` attributes?  `z-index` needs non-static positioned divs to work right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not possible in the much more complex "real" code, simplified version of which is presented here to emulate the problem. I fixed the issue by wrapping the bottom div with another one that has z-index:1 as was suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the order of the divs. Also if you are putting a link over another div which contains multiple divs, the overlay needs a backround. I usually use a transparent png. Otherwise the browser can see through it (ie7 etc).

Solution to problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Anytech/Gr3ae/1/