# z-index is not working in IE8.why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index, pseudo-element

I am trying to style the combobox with pure css and find some tutorial and created the combo box.It works fine on chrome and firefox.

Please take a look at the style I created.

[http://jsfiddle.net/SnU3d/1](http://jsfiddle.net/SnU3d/1/)

```
label
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
}


label:after 
{
    content:'?';
    font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#009FDF;
    font-size:120%;
    pointer-events:none;
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:30px;
    height:24px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    position:absolute;
    border-left:0px;
    right:-1px;
    z-index:99;
}
```

I found some other tutorials regarding this.[IE7 / IE8 z-index problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466695/ie7-ie8-z-index-problem),[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290191/z-index-broken-in-ie8).

So I put the zindex higher value for the parent label.But still the after pseudo element is not appearing in the IE8. why ? How can I make the after content visible.

Comment: Off-topic, but what do you think `font:11px ... font-size:120%` does?

Comment: Anyway, the first thing to check is if your page is rendered in standards compliance mode. In quirks mode, IE8 reverts to an older rendering engine, that does not support `content` and/or `:after`.

Comment: @MrLister fontsize is for making the triangle appear slightly bigger.I removed the font:11px ,sorry for that here. and I am getting the content in standard mode.Only issue is in z-index.

Comment: What Mr Lister is asking is do you have a doctype declared? If you don't, :after won't work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

The `:after` pseudo-element creates a child of the element you apply it to (`Label`), and the z-index value you assign to the parent (`label`), whatever that value is, creates a new stacking context inside that element, so you end up with a parent element (`label`) in the level 9999 of its stacking context, and a child element (`label:after`) in the level 99 of its own stacking context, for which the parent (`label`) is always going to be the background (the bottom).