# Why doesn't z-index work in ie8 even with all elements positioned

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I have two divs (top and bottom) and a div within the top div should overlap the bottom one. Despite looking at [common answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467477/43465) for this problem I still couldn't get it to work.

```
#above {
    position:relative;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(90%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 90%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
}

#under {
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 60px;
}

#tab {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 120px; width: 50%;
}

<div id="above">
 <div id="tab">Without filter</div>
</div>
<div id="under">Under</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the "filter" part which is commonly added for gradients to provide ie compatibility - like in the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Remove that and it all works fine. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielmee/QLuB8/1/) that shows the two but below is the one that works.

```
#above {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#under {
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 60px;
}

#tab {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 120px; width: 50%;
}

<div class="page">
    <div id="above">
        <div id="tab">
            Without filter
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="under">
    </div>
</div>
```